# > plot(model) Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Variable match was not found

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree, c5.0

```r
library(C50)
model <- C5.0(training$`Class variable`~ ., data = training[, -9])
plot(model)
pred <- predict.C5.0(model, testing[, -9])
a <- table(testing$`Class variable`, pred)

sum(diag(a))/sum(a)
```

here while plotting my model i am getting this error, kindly help me on this.

Comment: You shouldn't need `training$` in the formula, just `\`Class variable` ~ .` should suffice (assuming it is in `training`).

Comment: The error comes from here: https://github.com/topepo/C5.0/blob/master/R/as.party.C5.0.R#L252-L254. I don't know the `C50` package, unfortunately, so you should dig into what `!any(varp>0)` means and how to avoid it.